# Nginx (1.7.10) response 502 bad gateway through specific URL for REST API

Tags: backbone.js, nginx, jetty, dropwizard

```js
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # CACHING OF API RESPONSES
    # setup caching for the API Server responses
    # proxy_cache_path specifies the root directory for our cache, the directory-depth (levels), 
    # the max_size of the cache and the inactive expire time. 
    # More importantly, it specifies the size of the in-memory keys for the files through keys_zone. 
    # When nginx receives a request, it computes an MD5 hash and uses this key set to find the corresponding 
    # file on disk. If it is not available, the request will hit the API server
    proxy_cache_path  /var/cache/nginx/api levels=1:2 keys_zone=nrapi:8m max_size=3000m inactive=600m;
    proxy_cache_path  /var/cache/nginx/reportcard levels=1:2 keys_zone=nrreportcard:8m max_size=3000m inactive=600m;
    proxy_temp_path /var/tmp;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    log_format nrformat '$remote_addr $http_x_username $http_x_request_id [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                    '$request_time '
                    '$upstream_response_time';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  nrformat;
    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    #buffer optimizations
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 50m;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 8k;
    
    #timout optimizations
    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    send_timeout 10;
    
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #GZIP REQUESTS
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;

    # LOAD BALANCING FOR API SERVICES
    # load balancing API sevices
    upstream ona_api_services {
      #server 1
      server 127.0.0.1:8085;
      
      #minimum number of connections to keep alive to the api service
      keepalive 64; 
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        set $APP_ROOT /home/ubuntu/project/client;
        root $APP_ROOT;

        # REDIRECT HTTP TRAFFIC TO HTTPS
        # rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        #server side url re-write for fingerprinting of config.js
        location /static/app/modules/config {
            expires max;
            rewrite ^(.*)config(.*)\.js$ /app/modules/config.js break;
        }

        #server side url re-write for fingerprinting of nr-combined-style.js
        location /static/app/resources/css/nr-combined-style {
            expires max;
            rewrite ^(.*)nr-combined-style(.*)\.css$ /app/resources/css/nr-combined-style.css break;
        }

        #STATIC CACHING for all resources - css/js/image files
        location /static {
            autoindex on;
            access_log off;
            alias $APP_ROOT;
            expires max;
        }
        # Configuration to get the total number of active connections
        location /nginx_status {
            # Turn on stats
            stub_status on;
            access_log   off;
            # only allow access from localhost #
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
        }
        
        # PROXY SETUP FOR ONA API SERVICES    
        location /api/ {
            # CACHING OF API RESPONSES
            # This instructs nginx that it can use our api keys_set to cache incoming requests. 
            # MD5 hashes will be computed using the proxy_cache_key    
            proxy_cache nrapi;
            proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
            proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD;
            add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
            proxy_cache_valid any 24h;
            
            # SETUP of NO CACHE FOR OTHER API's
            set $no_cache "";

            if ($uri ~ "/api/v1/lessons/subject/*") {
                set $no_cache "1";
            }
            # Bypass cache if flag is set
            proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
            proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass         http://ona_api_services;     
        }

        # CHECK FOR NETWORK ERRORS ON THE CLIENT
        # DON'T CACHE THIS URL
        location /ping {
            autoindex on;
            access_log off;
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /app/templates/common/ping.json break;
            expires 0;
        }

        # DEFAULT MAPPING FOR THE SINGLE PAGE APPLICATION
        # DONT CACHE INDEX.HTML
        location / {
            autoindex on;
            expires 0;
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /app/index.html break;
        }
    }


}
```

I am working on web application which are built in require.js and Backbone.js that is running Nginx server(1.4.6).I am calling REST API (running on Jetty server) through Backbone Model.While hitting a specific URL, Nginx response 502 bad Gateway and it stucked.For example REST API url is 'http://window.protocol/api/user/{userId}' and its working fine for every userId except one userId=amit123.While i seen log on Jetty server(REST API),there is no request as 'http://window.protocol/api/user/amit123' from client site and the Logs on Nginx server are 502 Bad Gateway.I am attaching nginx.conf file code

Comment: Can you post the vhost configuration you're using? Nginx might have a regular expression in place to discriminate between user names and user numeric ids.

Comment: hey amenadiel, I have attached the Nginx.conf 's code.The REST API are running on PORT 8085 which have defined upstream ona_api_services{} method calling from location /api/... method.